# Will .NET allocate memory for the list?

Tags: c#

If I instantiated five objects of Employee class: emp1,emp2...emp5 and put them in a listA of IList. Now if I create another IList listB which contains subset of listA, for example

```
IList<Employee> listB = listA.Take(3).ToList()
```

are Employee objects in listB refrence to the same Employee in the listA?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the caveat that `.Take` doesn't create an `IList`.  If you wrote `listA.Take(3).ToList()`, then your description of the results (the list containing references to the same objects) would be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that; You will need to create a new list and add the items to it - which means it would be a copy. You think can also do that by using .ToList()